# Gartner quadrant chart of popular languages in 2016

Tags: feature-request

Something similar as the recent blog post:  [What Programming Languages Are Used Most on Weekends?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/What-Programming-Languages-Weekends/) Is there a general overview of languages used on SO in 2016? Preferable with some (Gartner) quadrant charts? And a comparison with the past? I would like to know which languages are trending, which ones are getting  unfashionable...?

And perhaps a comparison with the (yet to come) results of the 2017 developers survey?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can get "What programming languages cause the most problems" data, although it is tricky to separate from "What languages are most often used by newbies".  Actual good data for what you are interested in, no.  The PYPL index looks pretty reliable to me, unlike TIOBE.